# utc_offset is deprecated as of November 2019. Use utc_offset_minutes instead

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-maps

I'm currently receiving the following errors in my Vue component.

```
permanently_closed is deprecated as of May 2020 and will beturned off in May 2021. Use business_status instead

utc_offset is deprecated as of November 2019. Use utc_offset_minutes instead
```

Why am I receiving this deprecation warning if I didn't use that property?